# Remove push notifications listener React Native Expo

Tags: react-native, notifications, listener

I'm desperate trying to find out how to remove a listener.  In one of my screens I'm placing the listener inside the useEffect. However, I need to remove it once the persons leave, cancels or restarts the process.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

```
useEffect(() => {
Notifications.addListener(handlesNotifications);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is remove the listener with a return in your `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    Notifications.addListener(handlesNotifications);
    
    return () => {
        Notifications.removeListener();
    }
}, []);
```